# Open one curtain and you see another curtain

Tags: cipher

There are two sets of ciphers in this puzzle.

> Open one curtain and you see another curtain.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Message:

> Wisdom is the key to all locks

Method:

> Standard pigpen cipher (⌗,⌗•, ✕,✕•), then columnar transposition (`abcde`)